# Dynamic (database driven) Menu creation in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have just started hanging around in struts2 for the past few weeks. I have developed a login page and a landing page. But I have been struggling in creating a dynamic horizontal-menus based on user-accessibility defined in the database(mysql).
I have the following tables , say for example

```
menu_master
id | label | parent_id | action | etc | etc ...
```

If the parent_id is null then the corresponding label would be the parent menu and its children would come as sub-menus under it.Action would be the corresponding forward links

```
user
id | name | password | etc | etc |....

user_menu_mapping
id | user_id | menu_id
```

Based on this mapping table , I have to create a menu (generated at Java level and rendered as jsp [css+javascript]) when the user successfully logs into the system.

What are the best options and design procedures for dynamic menu generation available for struts2 application.

Any suggestions or advices are highly appreciated.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of separate parts that should be solved independently.

First consider the view... I would create an html page with css to look the way you want with a test menu.

Next using s2 tags get a list from an action class to prepare your menu. Is the menu just a s:select box? Do you mean a jquery drop down list based of an html unordered list? What ever it turns out to be use the appropriate S2 form or logic tags to build the menu from a List in the action class.

Now of course you need to dynamically build the List in the action... You can do this directly inside the action at this time but if you have a lot of database interaction your going to want to delegate this to a service layer.  In any case you now have the rather simple problem of getting the list you need from the database.

For us to help we'll need to know which one of these areas you're having problems with and what tools you are using... Probably the easiest would be to show your jsp/action class/and xml if any.